# Stop Appstate event trigger when user logs out

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this code using AppState to show a user a modal where  finger print scan is required to unlock the app once the app goes to background and comes back to active
In useEffect of the HomeScreen

```
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    };
```

method

```
  handleAppStateChange (nextAppState){
    if (nextAppState === 'active') {
     
     this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthModal');
     
    }
```

This all works fine and good. On a separate screen where I have my logout, when I logout  and get navigated to the login screen, the appState event is still triggered and I don't want that. The event should only be restricted to the AuthStack. I have tried a couple of things but no luck, how do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use [Async Storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) to handle that without [remove listener](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#removeeventlistener).
if you remove listener after logout you must listen again after login plus in app start.

solution with Async Storage without remove listener
you code may be look like this :

```js
//in logout function
const logout = async() => {
   await AsyncStorage.setItem('authState', "logout");
   ...
}
```

```js
//in login function
const login = async() => {
   await AsyncStorage.setItem('authState', "login");
   ...
}
```

and then wrap `this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthModal')` with if statment to check authentication

```js
handleAppStateChange (nextAppState){
    if (nextAppState === 'active') {
     
     (async() => {
        const authState = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authState');
        if(authState === "login"){
            this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthModal');
        }
     })();
     
    }
}
```